# Setting a validation rule on a custom object picklist

Tags: force.com, validation

I've looked all over, and I can't seem to get to the bottom of my issue.  I want validation to require a selection to be made in a picklist if a date has been entered in the previous field.  It currently looks like this:

```
AND (
  NOT(ISBLANK( $ObjectType.Binder__c.Fields.Bound_Date__c )),
  IF ( ($ObjectType.Binder__c.Fields.Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c) = "--None--", TRUE, FALSE
  )
)
```

I've also tried NOT ISBLANK/ISNULL, and I've tried parsing out the custom object name, to no avail.  How do I right the code to return the false, allowing the validation to pass, to force a move from --None-- to Yes or No?

Comment: Are you trying to check a condition and update a picklist value? in short are you trying to check if Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c is not '--None--' Bound_Date__c is not blank change and if it is none you want the Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c to be updated to either 'Yes' or 'No'? If the above is true you need a validation to say to prompt an error to the user and a workflow field update to update the Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c value

Comment: @rao, I'm trying to attempt the following; If a field is updated, and a picklist is not changed from the default null value, throw the validation error to tell the user to change that picklist to a 'yes' or 'no' value.  So I agree with you, but I can't seem to get the **$ObjectType.Binder__c.Fields.Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c** to be recognized within the validation rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:
Since we are dealing with picklist you will have to use ISPICKVAL() to compare the actual text value.

```
 AND (
    NOT(ISBLANK( $ObjectType.Binder__c.Fields.Bound_Date__c )),
    ISPICKVAL($ObjectType.Binder__c.Fields.Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c, "--None--")
    )
```

**Updated :**

since you are writing the val rule on the object itself you do not need $ObjectType just use the API name of the field and that should do.

```
 AND (
    NOT(ISBLANK(Bound_Date__c)),
    ISPICKVAL(Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c, "")
    )
```

In the validation message add "Please change Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c from None to yes or no value"

Comment: So I tried this, and here's the error message I got: 'Error: Incorrect parameter type for function **ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Object**. It just doesn't like that object with that function.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @rao:  you use ISPICKVAL twice.  You should only need it once.

Comment: @amatorVitae Sorry and thanks for pointing that sir :), was copy pasting between org and SE.

Comment: I tried your update, and I believe the error that came back was that it didn't recognize Bound_Date__c as a field.  I think I may have spotted the trouble though, in which the picklist I am trying to require once the field is filled...both live in a custom object (Binder__c)!  So I may not be able to perform this validation declaratively, and will have to require it through Apex.

Comment: @TheJ If you create a validation on the custom object Binder__c and if it has fields Bound_Date__c, Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c then the above formula should work, check if the API names for the fields are different. The validation rules apply the same way on a custom object as a standard object.

Comment: That's where I was going wrong!  I was living in the 'Customize' section, when I should have been looking for validation in the 'Create' -> Objects.  Thanks, @Rao!

Comment: Oh, and here's the final code I ended up using. `AND (
NOT(ISBLANK(Bound_Date__c)),
OR(
 NOT(ISPICKVAL( Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c, "Yes")),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Binder_Released_with_Subjectivities__c, "No"))
)
)`